# Grails 2.4.3 scriptlet blocks didn't parse html tags

Tags: html, grails, gsp, scriptlet

I'm trying to upgrade my grails application from 2.3.0 to 2.4.3.

I try to render a html codes by using scriptlet blocks, the code as shown below

```
<%="<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>"%>
```

Acutally, it should render as a href link but in 2.4.3 it just render the code as string, did somebody have the same issue and have any suggestion? This code works fine in 2.3.0 but 2.4.3.

Comment: What is the value of `grails.views.default.codec` in your `Config.vgroovy`?

Comment: `grails.views.default.codec="html"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your default codec is HTML escaping the entities within your String. If you need the raw string use `.encodeAsRaw()`

```
<%="<a href=\"http://foo.com\">foo</a>".encodeAsRaw()%>
```